# What is this constant $\lim_{a\to +\infty}(a-f(u)-\ln(a))=C$?

Tags: asymptotics, approximation, exponentiation, closed-form, hyperbolic-functions

### Problem :

Let the function on $x\in(0,1),a=\operatorname{constant}>1$ :

$$f(x)=x^{a^{x^{a}}}a^{x^{a^{x}}}-\operatorname{arctanh}(x)$$

Now let :

$$f'(u)=0,0.99<u<1$$

Then it seems we have :

$$\lim_{a \to +\infty} (a-f(u)-\ln(a))=C$$

Where $C$ is a constant

---

---

### Question :

Does this constant have a closed form or a nice approximation ?

Comment: Could you show some numbers ? I have a quite good approximation of $u$ but, if I am correct, $a-f(u)-\log(a)$ does not tend to a limit. May be, I misunderstood. Cheers :-)

Comment: Some *motivation* for this problem would be nice. Where does this function come from?  Why would this be a useful result?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici for $a=10000,f(u)\simeq 9988.27$ is it right ? I use Wolfram alpha . The problem is subtle.

Comment: There are a lot of overflows (even for $a=100$. Do we agree that, for $a=10$, $f(u)\sim 5.92780$ ? My estimate is $u=0.998485$ while the solution is $u=0.998339$. Please check and come back. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes I agree see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28x%5E10000%5Ex%5E10000%29%C3%97%2810000%5Ex%5E10000%5Ex%29-arctanh%28x%29%2Cx%3D0.999999999

Comment: That “Reference” was a bad joke. Are you trying to annoy the people who click on that YouTube link? Or is this just a random edit to attract more attention to the question?

Comment: Now i'm sure you are not a robot .

Comment: Some stuff added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first estimate of $u$, solution of $f'(u)=0$, is obtained by the simplest series expansion to $O(x-1)$
$$u_0=1-\frac{2}{4 a^2 (1+\log (a))-1}$$ which, by Darboux theorem, is an over estimate of the solution.

The next estimate $u_1$ will be explicitly given by the first iteration of any Newton like method of order $n$.

For example, for $a=10$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 u_0             & 0.998484887553 \\
 u_1^{(2)}       & 0.998352785241 \\
 u_1^{(3)}       & 0.998339082166 \\
 u_1^{(4)}       & 0.998338974554 \\
\cdots & \cdots \\
 \text{solution} & 0.998338974249 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

However, successive Newton iterations are quite better

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 u_0             & 0.998484887553 \\
 u_1^{(2)}       & 0.998352785241 \\
 u_2^{(2)}       & 0.998339099648 \\
 \cdots & \cdots \\
 \text{solution} & 0.998338974249 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

I shall use as solution $u=u_2^{(2)}$.

Computing
$$F(a)=a-f(u)-\log(a)$$ a lot of overflows happen as soon as $a >26$.

Nevertheless, Mathematica generates nice plots and the function $a\,F(a)$ *looks* to be a straight line with a slope close to $2.5$.

However, this is far to be sure since, using $u=u_0$, we have
$$\color{blue}{F(a)=\frac{1+2 \log (2)}{2} +\frac{1}{2} \log (1+\log (a))-}$$ $$\color{blue}{\frac{\log ^2(a)+5 \log (a)+1}{8 a
   (1+\log (a))^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^2}\right)}$$ which is bery good even for small values of $a$.

Notice that
$$\int \log (1+\log (a))\,da=a \log (1+\log (a))-\frac 1 e \text{Ei}(1+\log (a))$$ making, for $10^3 \leq a \leq 10^6$, the average value of the integrand equal to $2.62353$ and
$$\frac{1+2 \log (2)}{2} +\frac{1}{2}\times 2.62353=2.50491$$

*Probably* $$\lim_{a \to +\infty} (a-f(u)-\ln(a))$$ does not exist.

**Edit**

Let $(u_2,u_3,u_4,\cdots)$ be the first iterate of Newton, Halley and Householder,$\cdots$  methods (obtained starting at $u=0$). Asymptotically, we have

$$u_{n+1}-u_n=-\frac{ 1}{2^{n}\, (n-1)!\,\,a^{n+1}\, \log (a) }$$

Let $$G_k(a)=a-f(u_k)-\log(a)$$

Expanded as series to $O\left(\frac{1}{a^2}\right)$ for large values of $a$, they **all** lead to the "blue" formula.

Using more terms and $L=\log(a)$
$$G_4(a)=\frac{1+2 \log (2)}{2} +\frac{1}{2} \log (1+L)-\frac{L^2+5 L+1}{8 (L+1)^2\,a}-$$
$$\frac{14 L^4+38 L^3+62 L^2+13 L+2}{48 (L+1)^4\,a^2}-$$
$$\frac{57 L^6+520 L^5+1122 L^4+1479 L^3+352 L^2+81 L+9}{384 (L+1)^6\,a^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^4}\right)$$

Asymptotically
$$G_2(a)-G_3(a) \sim \frac{1}{16 a^2}$$

If there is an asymptotic, it would be
$$\underset{a\to \infty }{\text{limit}}\Bigg(\frac{a-f(u)-\log (a)}{\log
   (1+\log (a))}\Bigg)=\frac 12$$

Comment: So your end was not correct ? (sorry i cannot upvote twice)

Comment: @ErikSatie  nothing changed.same conclusions WITH différent estimates off $u$